# C# Check and then convert dd/MM/yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#

How can I check if a date (a string)  is dd/MM/yyyy and then covert it to MM/dd/yyyy.

I have some dates in Euro format like  - 25/12/2020

I need to check the format and then convert to MM/dd/yyyy   - 12/25/2020

Since it's a string.. I guess the only thing I can do is check if the first digits are > 12?

```
row["DATE"].ToString().Substring(0, row["DATE"].ToString().IndexOf("/"))) > 12
```

Is my option only to 'switch' the positions for can I use a date function

Comment: You're not trying to check that the number isn't already MM/dd/yyyy, I hope? If you are, then the problem is that you have dates like 12/08/2020. Is that the 12th of August, or the 8th of December? Should it be converted or not?

Comment: It looks like you are reading the column "DATE" from a database table. If yes, then the date is probably stored in the database in a way that is independent of any format. What is the datatype of the "DATE" column in the database?

Comment: values are strings - output of OCR of various documents. Some are 12/25/2020 and some 25/12/2020.  Maybe if the first digits are greater than 12 I convert. Not sure if there  is a clear solution.

Comment: There isn't a clear solution, so it's definitely unwise to try and automate this. You need to define a process by which you, as a human, can determine if a document's date is in dd/MM/yyyy format or MM/dd/yyyy format. If you can then automate that process, great. If not, I don't think there is a good solution except to come up with some kind of compromise.

Comment: Can you determine where the document is coming from, to *extract* a Culture from it, somehow? If you can then you may have a DateTimeFormat you can use. Unless these documents don't follow specific culture rules either (as some official Community documents in Europe, where the Date format is specific per type of document).

Comment: **You can't**. `01/02/2020` could be either Jan 2 or Feb 1, and either is equally likely. But this sure looks like it came out of a database. The real fix here is _not storing dates in varchar columns in the first place!_

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn *values are strings - output of OCR of various documents*.

Answer (score 0):

For checking a string is a date , use
DateTime.TryParseExact method.
Then use ToString method for change format of this date.

Comment: This isn't a good solution in this scenario. There's no way to definitively determine which format the dates belong to.